# I want to have a overlay using css but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a overlay dialog box using CSS . I wrote the css but I am not able to display the overlay dialog box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Check out my attempt here. Also this should work in IE9 and firefox.
[http://jsfiddle.net/tGDKT](http://jsfiddle.net/tGDKT/9/)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jquery 1.2.6?  That's very old.

Comment: actually the jsp page i am working on uses 1.2.6 or 1.5.1

Comment: 1.2.5 **OR** 1.5.1? thats a big **OR**

Answer (score 1):

why not just use jQuery UI's dialog:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/tGDKT/15/

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        $('iframe').dialog();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting "calculateEmbeddedWindowSize is not defined" in the console. Your javascript does not seem to be there at all on the page.

Edit - Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tGDKT/7/

Comment: Change the jsFiddle option to load(head)

Answer (score 0):

You could also attach the method in the javascript, unobtrusive style.  Give the `<a>` an id or:

```
$('a').click(calculateEmbeddedWindowSize);
```

... would call the function for every link on the page.